# Cannot grab returned x, y float values from list to use in point distance

Tags: python, list, point, attributeerror, euclidean-distance

I'm new to python, and programming in general and am struggling to understand why I can't access the x, y coordinates of the list I created `ranlist` to use as variables in my math module distance formula.

Here is the entirety of my code, however the step of defining the function `closestpt` is where I am hung up, and within the function, `ranlist.x`, `ranlist.y` is where I get an

> AttributeError: list object has no attribute 'x'

Can someone explain to me why `ranlist` does not have 'x' and 'y' as attributes, and how I can access the x,y points in the list `ranlist`? When I step through the code and debug I can see the random float values generated

```
import math
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=0):                      
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z
        self.dem=2
        if (z!=0):
            self.dem=3
    def print_coordinate(self):
        print "The x coordinate is %s, the y coordinate is %s, and the z coordinate is %s" % (self.x, self.y, self.z)
    def calc_distance(self, next1):
        try:
            if (self.z==0):
                dx = self.x - next1.x
                dy = self.y - next1.y
                return math.hypot(dx,dy)                            
            else:
                threedist = ((self.x - next1.x)^2 + (self.y - next1.y)^2 + (self.z - next1.z)^2)
                return math.sqrt(threedist)
        except(SyntaxError, IndexError, TypeError) as e:
            print e


cord1 = Point(0,1,4)
cord2 = Point(0,4,0)
print cord1.print_coordinate()
print cord1.calc_distance(cord2)


import random
a = 10
b = 20
val = random.uniform(a,b)

ranlist = []
def ranpoint(num_point, dimension, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    for i in range(num_point):
        x = random.uniform(lower_bound, upper_bound)
        y = random.uniform(lower_bound, upper_bound)
        ranlist.append(Point(x,y,0))
    return ranlist
print ranpoint

print ranpoint(100, "2d", 0, 100)
rantest = ranpoint(100, '2d', 0, 100)



def closestpt():
    cordt = Point(50,50)
    dist1 = []
    for i in range(0, 100):
        ndx = cordt.x - ranlist.x
        ndy = cordt.y - ranlist.y
        dist2 = math.hypot(ndx,ndy)
        dist1.append(dist2)
    return dist1

print closestpt()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `ranlist` which is a [`list`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). You `append` a `Point` to it. So now `ranlist` has 1 object inside it of type `Point`.

To access this object you could run `ranlist[0].x` and `ranlist[0].y` which will access the first member of the list (in index `0`) and retrieve the value of `x` and `y` respectively.

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you! So i guess it was nothing more than specifying an index within the list. Ahhh, so simple! I think the error confused me as it made me think there was no x attributes.